# Parameterize logic app with weekly recurrence trigger

Tags: azure-logic-apps

This page shows how to parameterize logic app with an hourly recurrence trigger

[Recurrence Logic app Activity ARM template automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60657112/recurrence-logic-app-activity-arm-template-automation)

How do I do the same with a weekly recurrence trigger?  It should run Monday-Friday 09:00-17:00 on the hour and every 15 minutes thereafter.

This helps, but I can't quite fit it in to a parameters file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#recurrence-trigger

The schedule will be different in production, test and development environments. We want the ARM template to be the same for all environments. Therefore, we will need different parameter files for each environment. In this answer the schedule appears to have been hard coded into the ARM template.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Recurrence` Trigger in logic app workflow having a week frequency which actually allows us to select timings i.e., hours and days that we want our workflow to be triggered.

[image]

and below is my ARM template

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workflows_<LogicAppName>_name": {
            "defaultValue": "<LogicAppName>",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_<LogicAppName>_name')]",
            "location": "centralus",
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "triggers": {
                        "Recurrence": {
                            "recurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Week",
                                "interval": 1,
                                "schedule": {
                                    "hours": [
                                        "9",
                                        "10",
                                        "11",
                                        "12",
                                        "13",
                                        "14",
                                        "15",
                                        "16",
                                        "17"
                                    ],
                                    "weekDays": [
                                        "Monday",
                                        "Tuesday",
                                        "Wednesday",
                                        "Thursday",
                                        "Friday"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Week",
                                "interval": 1,
                                "schedule": {
                                    "hours": [
                                        "9",
                                        "10",
                                        "11",
                                        "12",
                                        "13",
                                        "14",
                                        "15",
                                        "16",
                                        "17"
                                    ],
                                    "weekDays": [
                                        "Monday",
                                        "Tuesday",
                                        "Wednesday",
                                        "Thursday",
                                        "Friday"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "Recurrence"
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {},
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please try checking the updated answer

Comment: The schedule will be different in production, test and development environments.  We want the ARM template to be the same for all environments.  Therefore, we will need different parameter files for each environment.  In this answer the schedule appears to have been hard coded into the ARM template.

Answer (score 0):

After defined the structure of the recurrence, you may define one or more parameters. Then you can provide different values for those parameters at deploy time, for the different environments.

This can be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-parameters-workflows?tabs=consumption

[image]